Airflow can't fetch logs from remote docker workers. Name or service not known
I have two nodes airflow setup, on one node there is webserver, several workers, scheduler. Node number two have only workers.For workers I use celery. But webserver can't fetch logs from node number two.
Error:
    docker id
*** Log file does not exist: path
*** Fetching from: http://docker id:8793/path
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Initially I have 5 workers, but if I reduce that number to one, expose port :8793 in docker and use hostname of my node than everything works fine and logs are fetched.
So how can I extend it to 5 workers instead of just one without use of remote storage? And is it even possible?
